# Writing a plug-in to animate using scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I want to create a JQuery Plugin to animate elements using scrollbar by changing the position of the selected item.

I need something like this :

```
$("#obj").scrollate(200,400,"left:100","left:400");
```

Then I need to access .scroll function on each function ? !!!

I think this code does won't work because the .scroll function cannot be declared for each instant separately!

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.scrollate = function (start,end) {

//Some code

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var spos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (spos > start && spos < end) {
            var progress = (1 / (end - start)) * (spos - start);

            // changing css using progress
        }
    }
})
```

})(JQuery);

Comment: Are you saying this is working and you're wondering if that's a proper way? Or is it not working as you intend?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>scroll demo</title>
<style>
div {
color: blue;
}
p {
color: green;
}
span {
color: red;
display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Try scrolling the iframe.</div>
<p>Paragraph - <span>Scroll happened!</span></p>
<script>
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
$( window ).scroll(function() {
$( "span" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Give this a try. Its referenced from jquerys knowledge base on [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/);

Also- this may or may not help but another working example with some html and css:
http://lab.stephaneguigne.com/js/jquery-scrollsections/example/callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks very usefull examples ...But I want to animate CSS properties with scrollbar. Then I need to add this effect to multiple objects . each with a separated "$(window).scroll(function () "  . This is the problem. I will add more info to the question

Comment: Thanks yeah, I dont think Im understanding clearly in that case. To .animate css w/jquery - try this http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GELTP/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery plugin available for scrolling  [jQuery scrollto](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

It has options for animating scrolling also